# Do non-Schengen flight crews working in and out of the area, fall foul of the 90/180 day rule?

Tags: visas, air-travel, schengen, europe, 90-180-visa-rules

Just want to know whether it affects Flight crews availability to work… thanks in advance.

Comment: Related: [What schengen visa should the flight crew from outside the EU have?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/132335/241)

Comment: It may also depend on whether they need to pass immigration on their Schengen journeys. I see many UK flights turn around with the same crew, who do not even leave the plane between flights.

Comment: @Willeke passing immigration is not of itself the controlling factor; air crew can pass immigration without getting a stamp under routine circumstances.

Comment: I do not fully understand your question. It is about mixing normal Schengen entry with crew entry or just crew entry? In such last case, your airline will do paperwork and check conditions (and also required rest periods): they know a lot better then people on this side (also if we were pilots, we do not care about it). In any case the 90/180 rule is just one rule for specific type of entries, not for crew (or many other type of visa)

Answer (score 4):

Normally, flight crew members will enter the Schengen area on the basis of a pilot's license or crew certificate (see Annex VII, item 2 of the [Schengen Borders Code](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=CELEX%3A02016R0399-20190611)), which is not to be stamped (see Article 11(2)).

The code does not contain an explicit exemption from the 90/180 rule in such cases, but the explicit exemption of these documents from being stamped is an implicit exemption from the 90/180 rule because the stamps are the record by which presence in the Schengen area is calculated.